# "Cohomology with compact support isomorphic to homology" theorems

Tags: cohomology, etale-cohomology

I am collecting theorems throughout different fields which say roughly something of the form "Cohomology with compact support isomorphic to homology".

I'm studying this situation (and its relative version for a map $f : X \rightarrow Y$) since I'm interested in ultimately pursuing poincaré duality for étale cohomology.

It would be really nice to have some easier toy examples, say for complex manifolds (and singular cohomology), and maybe some examples of manifolds where the theorem doesn't hold (presumably, topological manifolds?). Also maps of manifolds.

I am hoping ultimately to see how the smoothness condition comes to play in étale cohomology, but also I have seen that there are generalizations to do with the condition of being normal.

Comment: The Poincare duality isomorphism between singular homology and cohomology with compact support does hold for topological manifolds, so smoothness is irrelevant, see e.g. Hatcher's "Algebraic topology".

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Thanks Igor. Do you know anything about the relative version of poincare duality (for maps)?

Comment: What does "for maps" mean? Reading on PD (in Hatcher or any other standard book) may help you isolate what you want to ask. In Bredon's "Sheaf theory" you will find a version of Poincare duality for sheaf cohomology; perhaps this is closer to your interest.

Comment: The relative version is usually called Verdier or Poincaré-Verdier duality. It holds in both the topological and étale settings. You can take a look at the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verdier_duality and references there for more details.